# Facebook every time denied new permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

I need user_posts permission on my web http://www.slevnime.cz/ and facebook every time deny this review with this message:

> user_posts - Web - We could not reproduce the requested permission. Please
>   submit detailed, step-by-step English instructions in the "Add Notes"
>   section of the permission, and make sure to provide the relevant
>   version of your app. See here for additional information on login
>   permission requirements.

When people logging on my app, i ask for this permissions: email, publish_actions, user_friends and user_posts. Why facebook send me this message? Detailet step-by-step is writed fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: _“Detailet step-by-step is writed fine”_ – no, apparently _not_.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ask Facebook says, you should outline why and for what you need the `user_posts` permission. It should also be visible to them where in your application this is used.

If they can't see this, they will not grant you the permission.